# Django checkbox in forms to filter objects

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox

I've a doctor database and trying to implement filters. I want to add a checkbox for Online Booking that people can select to filter all the doctors available for online booking. In the Doctor entity I've a boolean field `bookinReq` which is default to False. Doctors with online booking have the field to True.  I'm not sure how to implement the checkbox in the forms.

## doclisting.html

```
        <select class="form-control" id="speciality" name="speciality">
          <option value="All Doctors"><b>Choose Speciality...</b></option>
          {% for value, text in form.speciality.field.choices %}
            {% if value == s_name %}
              <option selected="selected" value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
            {% else %}
              <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </select>



        <select class="form-control" id="language" name="language">
            <option><b>Choose Language</b></option>
            {% for l in languages %}
              {% if l.name == l_name %}
                <option selected="selected" value="{{ l }}">{{ l }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ l }}">{{ l }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
         <div class="form-control" id="bookinReq" name="bookinReq">
            <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="bookingReq">  Online Booking
            </label>
          </div>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="ss-submit">Search</button>
        </span>
      </form>
```

## views.py

```
def filter_doctors(request=None, specialization=None, language=None bookinReq=None):

    query = Doctor.objects.filter()

    if specialization and specialization != "All Doctors":
        try:
            spec = Specialization.objects.get(name = specialization) 
            query = query.filter(specialization=spec)
        except:
            return None
    if language and language != "Choose Language":
        try:
            lang = Language.objects.get(name=language)
            query = query.filter(language=lang)
        except:
            return None
    if bookinReq is True:
        query = query.filter(bookinReq = True)
    return query



def doclistings(request): 
    d = getVariables(request)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = DropdownSelectionForm(request.GET)
        try:
            s_name = request.GET['speciality']
        except:
            s_name = None
        try:
            l_name = request.GET['language']
        except:
            l_name = None

        try:
            bookinReq = request.GET['bookinReq']
        except:
            bookinReq = None

        d['s_name'] = s_name 
        d['l_name'] = l_name
        d['bookinReq'] = bookinReq

        try:
            doctors = filter_doctors(request=request, specialization=s_name, language=l_name, bookinReq = bookinReq)

        except Exception:
            return error404(request)

        if doctors == None: # error during filteration, rended 404
            return error404(request)

        if len(doctors) == 0:
            d['not_found'] = "anything you want here :)"


    else:
        form = DropdownSelectionForm()


    d.update({'form': form, 'languages': Language.objects.all()})
    return render_to_response('m1/doclistings.html',d, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## forms.py

```
class DropdownSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    speciality = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES, widget = forms.Select, required = False)
```

Comment: Could you please show DropdownSelectionForm code?

Comment: I've updated the code with the form

Answer (score 0):

To declare a boolean is pretty simple all you have to add this one liner code.

```
bookinReq = forms.BooleanField(required=True, initial=False)
```

Aside from your question here few things that may save you sometime in the future.

```
try:
    s_name = request.GET['speciality']
except:
    s_name = None

# That block of code can be replace with
s_name = request.GET.get('speciality', None)    # the second param is the default value
```

The way you render form requires a lot of code. You should consider look into form rendering from dj website. A much better route is crispy form, once you use it you don't want to use anything else.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/
http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

```
<select class="form-control" id="speciality" name="speciality">
  <option value="All Doctors"><b>Choose Speciality...</b></option>
  {% for value, text in form.speciality.field.choices %}
    {% if value == s_name %}
      <option selected="selected" value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
    {% else %}
      <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</select>

# here is some what equivalent version
<select class="form-control" id="speciality" name="speciality">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

That's all from me, good luck :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anyway to implement the checkbox without the crispy form?

Comment: that syntax is not crispy, it's django native